# Yeoman angular automatic vendors JS not adding

Tags: angularjs, git, reactjs, webpack, bower

Im developing `angularjs` app with yeoman and all views are created with `reactjs`, packages controlled with `webpack` `npm` and `bower`, whenever I add new vendor package with bower from `git` `yeoman` suppose to inject it to `html` footer but it wont.

```
bower install isotope
```

but packages are downloading to vendor folder but not injected to `html` footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you have to add --save flag when you add new packages from bower to know yeoman this need library is required.

```
bower install isotope --save
```